# I want to chage a Image after I update a Image to Imageview in recyclerview

Tags: android, image, imageview

Now I have a problem with image changing of recyclerview.

This is my activity java code

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(photo_upload_Activity.this);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(photo_upload_Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.edit_box, null, false);
            builder.setView(view);
            btn_upload = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload1);
            edit_photo_title = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_photo_title);
            edit_phto_content = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_photo_content);

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();


            btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    title = edit_photo_title.getText().toString();
                    content = edit_phto_content.getText().toString();
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            dialog.show();
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:

            imageUri = data.getData();

            photolist.add(new photoInfo(imageUri, "Title : " + title, "Content : " + content));
            try {

                myAdpayer = new photoAdapter(photo_upload_Activity.this, photolist);
                mRecycler.setAdapter(myAdpayer);
                //img_upload_picture.setImageURI(imageUri);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

and this is part of Adapter code

```
    PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener popupClick = new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {// 사진올린후 수정 버튼 눌릴시
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu3:


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

here is promble.

I want to change a image from gallery at the switch -> case R.id.menu3; but i can't override the onActivitiyResult  method so i couldn't access the gallery

how can I call the method onActivityResult in the Adapter java file???

and sorry my bad english.. T^T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet of my code that you might want to apply for [image: updating image]